Find $m \in \mathbb{Z} $ so that all roots of $x^2-mx+m+2=0$ are also integers.
I need a little help on this. I know $\Delta=m^2-4m+4, \Delta\ \ge0$ because I need my roots to be integers. From this one i get $$m\in(-\infty,2-2\sqrt{3}] \cup [2+2\sqrt{3},\infty).$$ Also $S=m, P=m+2$, because roots are integers, their sum must be an integer so $m\in \mathbb{Z}$
My idea was to take two separate cases, first when $m$ is positive second when $m$ is negative.
For the first case I put $\Delta$ between 2 consecutive perfect squares, namely $(m-3)^2<m^2-4m+4<(m-2)^2$. From the first inequality I get $m\ge9$, but between 2 perfect squares there are no perfect squares so $m$ must be lesser than 9. I also know that $m\in[2+2\sqrt{3},\infty)$ and it's also an integer so the only options I get are $m\in \{6,7,8\}$. When I check them, the only one that works is $6$.
Now for the second case, when $m$ is negative, I am a little stuck. I tried to do the same, taking 2 consecutive perfect squares and writing them as $(m-k)^2 <m^2-4m+4<(m-2)^2$. I tried to find something similar to the first case but I don't know how to go further. I guessed that the negative solution is $m=-2$ but I don't know how to prove it rigorous.

Check your discriminant calculation

I am sorry OP I misread the problem

You're right with $m=-2$ OP

Please do not answer in the comments.

To use your approach OP: The determinant of $x^2 - mx +(m+2)$ is in fact $m^2-4m-8 = (m-2)^2-12$. So for the polynomial $x^2-mx +(m+12)$ to have integral roots, $(m-2)^2-12$ has to be an integral square. There are not too many nonnegative integers $y$ such that there is another integer $x$ such that $x^2$ and $y^2$ are distinct squares with $0<y^2-x^2 \le 12$. In particular, $y=|m-2|$ cannot be any larger than $6$ while $y^2=(m-2)^2$ must be at least $12$ so $y=|m-2|$ must be at least $4$. This leaves only a few choices for $|m-2|$ to check directly whether $|m-2|^2-12$ is a square namely, $|m-2| =4,5,6$.
So checking directly, it is necessary and sufficient that $|m-2|=4$. This gives $m= -2,6$. For $m=-2$ the polynomial is $x^2+2x$ which has $-2$ and $0$ as roots; for $m=4$ the polynomial is $x^2-6x+8$ which has $2$ and $4$ for roots.

I think you need to consider another the way for solve it.
We can use the fact that a polynomial with integer coefficients and integer roots satisfies the Viète's Theorem (Theorem for divisors of the constant term). Let be $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ solutions for the equation. By the theorem:
$$
\begin{align*}
r_{1} + r_{2} =& m & \text{ The sum of the roots equals }m \\
r_{1}\cdot r_{2} =& m+2 & \text{ Te product of roots, from the constant term}
\end{align*}
$$
Solving that little system, you can obtain the roots and naturally the values for $m$.
The following is the answer for the question:

 Roots are $r_{1} = 2$ and $r_{2} = 4$ for $m=6$ and  $r_{1} = 0$ and $r_{2} = -2$ for $m=-2$

Edit:
For solving the system, is necessary to write the second equation in terms of $m$: $$m = r_{1}\cdot r_{2}-2$$ and relationate that with the first one. After that, reorganize that euality into a "kind" square equation and add +1 in both sides. With that you will be able to factorize and find the roots and naturally the $m$'s.

Actually, the OP's (i.e. original poster's) interrogation of the discriminant represents the beginning of a sound approach.  See my answer.

Alternative approach:
The roots are
$$\frac{1}{2} ~\left[ ~m \pm \sqrt{m^2 - 4m - 8} ~\right].$$
Because of the $~\frac{1}{2}~$ scalar above, there are two constraints that must be satisfied.

$m^2 - 4m - 8$ must be a perfect square.

$\displaystyle \sqrt{m^2 - 4m - 8}~$ and $~m~$ must have the same odd-even parity.


To satisfy both conditions, there must exist some integer $~k~$ such that $~k~$ and $~m~$ have the same odd-even parity, and such that;
$$k^2 = m^2 - 4m - 8 = (m-2)^2 - 12 \implies $$
$$[ ~(m - 2) - k ~] \times [ ~(m - 2) + k ~] = (m - 2)^2 - k^2 = 12.$$
Since $~m~$ and $~k~$ are required to have the same parity, and since $~m~$ and $~(m-2)~$ do have the same parity, the two factors of $~[ ~(m - 2) - k ~]~$ and $~[ ~(m - 2) + k ~]~$ must both be even.  Further, the only way of factoring $~12~$ into two even factors is by $~(2,6)~$ and $~(-2,-6).$
Further, you have that $~(m - 2) = \dfrac{[ ~(m - 2) - k ~] + ~[ ~(m - 2) + k ~]}{2}.$
Therefore, $~(m-2)~$ must equal $~\pm \dfrac{6 + 2}{2} = \pm 4.$  Therefore, the only candidate values for $~m~$ are $~\{6,-2\}.$
Both candidate values are manually verified as satisfactory.
